# How to have a div that has 100% height and overflow scroll

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to have a 100% div height so that based on the variety on screen sizes it looks good, but then I need the ul to be scrollable if the content is to large and will not fit in the screen.

HTML

```
<div id="category_modal_body" class="modal-body">
    <div id="category_filters" class="row">
        <div id="category_list" class="col-md-4">
            <ul>
               <li> ... </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
     </div>
 </div>
<div id="category_modal_footer" class="modal-footer">
    <div id="category_selected_path"></div><div id="category_footer_buttons">
        <button type="button" id="add_another_category">Tjeter</button>
        <button type="button" id="add_category_path">Përfundo</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

`CSS:`

```
#category_modal_body #category_list{
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%
}
#category_modal_body #category_list ul{
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height:100%;
    overflow:scroll;
}
```

This is the result I got:

[image]

So u can see how the last buttons go over the div.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

First thing I would try is putting `category_modal_footer` div inside `category_modal_body` div, like this:

```
<div id="category_modal_body" class="modal-body">
    <div id="category_filters" class="row">
        <div id="category_list" class="col-md-4">
            <ul>
                <li>...</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="category_modal_footer" class="modal-footer">
        <div id="category_selected_path"></div>
        <div id="category_footer_buttons">
            <button type="button" id="add_another_category">Tjeter</button>
            <button type="button" id="add_category_path">Përfundo</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: And how would this fix the problem?